# Values in dynamically added controls not retained on postback

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a page with a number of controls of type `MyControl` added dynamically. The count is stored in the `ViewState`, and only incremented with a button click.

In `MyControl`, I have a `TextBox` control, and a `Label` control. When the text is changed in the textbox, the value is multiplied by 2 and displayed in the label control.

To do this, I have added an `OnTextChanged` event and set `AutoPostBack` to true.

My problem is this: when I have any number of `MyControl`'s on the page, and change the text in any of the textboxes, the label is updated and the values are retained on postback.

However, if I click the increment button on the page, all the values in the textboxes and labels are lost.

My code:

**Default.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Test.Default" EnableViewState="true" %>

<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        Count:
        <asp:Label ID="lblCount" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        <asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" OnClick="btnAdd_Click" Text="+" />
        <asp:Panel ID="pnlControls" runat="server"></asp:Panel>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Default.aspx.cs**

```
public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int count = 0;

        //if not postback, then set count and store in viewstate
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            count = 1;
            ViewState["count"] = count;
        }

        LoadControls();
    }

    protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //increment count 
        ViewState["count"] = (int)ViewState["count"] + 1;
        pnlControls.Controls.Clear();

        LoadControls();
    }

    private void LoadControls()
    {
        //add controls to page
        for (int i = 0; i < (int)ViewState["count"]; i++)
        {
            MyControl con = (MyControl)LoadControl("MyControl.ascx");
            con.ID = i.ToString();

            pnlControls.Controls.Add(con);
        }

        //set count label
        lblCount.Text = ViewState["count"].ToString();
    }

}
```

**MyControl.ascx**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MyControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="Test.MyControl" EnableViewState="true" %>

<div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtField" runat="server" OnTextChanged="txtField_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Label ID="lblAnswer" runat="server" Text="answer:"></asp:Label>
</div>
```

**MyControl.ascx.cs**

```
public partial class MyControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{

    public string Text;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void txtField_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblAnswer.Text = (int.Parse(txtField.Text) * 2).ToString();
    }
}
```

Am I missing something obvious? How can I keep the values when the button is clicked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you lose the info of MyControl(s..) is when you click the button you clear them:

```
 pnlControls.Controls.Clear();
```

If you want to keep the values I recomended you to use Session variables, for example an array when you fire "txtField_TextChanged" to save "lblAnswer.Text", be carefull with the ID's to differentiate from each other in the Session variable.

Finally, I'd put "LoadControls();" inside Page_Load, outside I think It's redundant.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The reason I clear the controls and have the `LoadControls()` in the click event method are so that the button click adds another control to the page. Without this, the control is not added until the next postback.

Comment: Yes, and that's OK, but it's the reason you lose the values inside the controls, use a Session variable to avoid this.